# I am unable to ask questions, and I can't see why I am banned?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, post-ban

I know very well that if a user posts a significant number of low quality questions or questions that do not fit the standards then they will be blocked from asking questions.

And the block is not fixed about how much time it will take to be able to ask a new question. Also it is not removed after making a request for removal.

I could not find a reason for my ban because:

1. I have asked my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529631/netstarter?tab=questions&sort=newest) on June 18 - It has been close to a month from then.
2. The question which I asked did not get a downvote - though it also not received any greater response
3. Don't know exactly whether the answer section is considered for banning a user for asking question but in the answering section as well I have not received any downvotes for an answer; also, none have been deleted.

It is quite surprising to have been banned like this. Is there any reason to be banned like this ?

Comment: Could it be a shared IP problem?

Comment: @AzizShaikh What does it means ? would like to know what problem you are talking about

Comment: Are you on a network which is used by multiple users? Maybe some other user who was also using Stack Exchange was banned. Maybe your shared IP has been temporarily restricted by Stack Exchange system.

Comment: @AzizShaikh Yes it is on shared network but don't know who are using Stack Exchange and who are not but it is quite disappointing :(

Comment: Have you *deleted* any questions recently? And what is the exact message you get when posting a question?

Comment: I guess someone else who is using your IP got banned and tried to bypass it by creating more and more accounts, which led the team to put IP ban. Look for different network.

Comment: @MartinSmith no there are no recent question deleted by me and the message is "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more."

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd i will not be able to use another network as i am not using personal internet,i will try by changing my IP address whether it works or not lets check.thanks for your reply

Comment: "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this **account**..." - that needs clarification. Is it the account itself or IP? anybody knowns that for sure?

Comment: @mehow - The reason I asked the question was because I assumed the messages would be different and give some clue but [looks like this is not the case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294)

Comment: The ban does not seem to be in effect any longer - you were _almost_ out from under it when you posted this, and a few up votes seemed to have made the difference. Congratulations for successfully working your way out of it, you should treat it as a bit of an accomplishment.

Comment: Timpost yes the ban is lifted out now i am able to ask question and @downvoter it will be great help for me for future if you explain the reason....thanks to all for help...

Comment: everytime i ask a question it prompt that you have not met standard why ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deleted questions also count towards the criteria for a question ban (keep in mind I do not know the exact algorithm, I've only seen instances where a user claims he is Q-banned and correlated that to the state of their questions).

In your case, you have two deleted questions which would still count, even though they can never be upvoted (because they're deleted):

- [javascript works fine with IE but not with firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250742/javascript-works-fine-with-ie-but-not-with-firefox-and-chrome)
- [I want to show my websites visitor the flag of there country when they login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700523/i-want-to-show-my-websites-visitor-the-flag-of-there-country-when-they-login)
  *(titles pasted from the questions)*

For some of your other questions, they have downvotes, and this counts towards what would induce a question ban.

My advice to you is to [follow the advice listed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers), and work to improve your deleted questions and get them undeleted.

Comment: The deleted questions are **quite old** and probably do not apply anymore. Also I see no reason why if the most recent of those deleted questions was deleted in April of this year, then why was the OP able to ask a new question in June?

Comment: His last question wasn't bad (0 score). Shouldn't the ban kick in after bad question, and prevent the last one from being asked?

Comment: The question ban algorithm takes all questions into account. From what I can discern (based on publicly available knowledge), it takes votes into account, even if those votes are from deleted questions. If you have a question that is at -2 and deleted, and you get another -2 from an active question, you could conceivably be banned, but not attribute it to the total state of your questions. (Again, the exact algorithm is secret and I do not know it. These numbers are used for example purposes).  So you could be question banned months after posting a bad question due to downvotes.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker thanks for the answer i will try to make the deleted question more clean and clear also would like to inform you all that now i am able to ask a question.Thanks for your support guys...:)

Answer (score 1):

OK, based on the comments and other meta answers, I see only two possible solutions in this case:

- You were either banned by mistake (which I personally doubt - nothing against you)
- or as the above suggestions from comments - you (or someone else on your network) have been posting *extremely* poor questions (possibly deleted now).

I cannot find any other reasonable cause for your account to be banned.

What I would like to see is some sort of history print out related to your [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address).

What I recommend you to do (in case you're not guilty) is to follow the recommendations in  Meta Stack Overflow question *[What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997)*.

Comment: **You were either banned by mistake (which I personally doubt - nothing against you)**  - May be the case.
**You (or someone else on your network) have been posting extremely poor questions. (possibly deleted now)** - I have not posted any question since June 18(Don't know anyone else using the Stack Exchange
**What I would like to see is some sort of history print out related to your IP** - what kind of history ?
**What I recommend you to do ( in case you are not guilty ) -> follow this** - i have gone through this before there is no way out

Comment: related to your IP address, how many SO accounts are associated with your IP etc.

Comment: Sorry i can't provide such details... thanks for the help

Comment: obviously I know that - that's more likely directed towards admins or/and people with privileges and skils to [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/)