# Why do I still have a question ban?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, post-ban

> We are no longer accepting questions from this account

I got this notification a month ago when I tried to ask a new question. I read the FAQ and understood why I got this ban and how to get rid of it. I started contributing positively to the site after that. I fixed the posts that I think caused the ban (some were edited, some were deleted). Some of the edited posts got positive votes. Also, I answered some questions, and one got accepted, one got up-voted and no answers were downvoted.

So, what can be done to get rid of this ban?

P.S. There are two questions -- one on-hold and other closed. I've just edited them but I can't delete them as they're having answers.

Comment: Note regarding "i can't delete them because of they are have answer", **do not delete questions** it makes the ban worse

Comment: I only see [one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2713934/refaat?tab=answers) in your Stack Overflow account. Where are the others?

Comment: Your profile looks fine so you must have deleted downvoted questions

Comment: @AmalMurali this is not my acount, this is my [stackoverflow account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1638739/muhammed-refaat)

Comment: @RichardTingle this is not my acount, this is my [stackoverflow account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1638739/muhammed-refaat)

Comment: The ban is not time dependent. It will not simply expire if you wait long enough. You need to make an effort to improve questions in order to lift it.

Comment: @Oded answering other questions don't help ?

Comment: @Refaat every contribution helps, but in general, fixing your old questions and getting them undeleted and upvoted is far more effective and carries more weight towards getting unbanned than just answering questions

Comment: @Refaat Why do you have two accounts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ban still exists because a sufficient proportion of your questions haven't been improved enough to recieve upvotes. This is because many of your questions (as you say in your question) are deleted and so cannot be upvoted.

You appear to believe that deleting posts counts as fixing them, I'm afraid that under the [rules of the ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) deleted questions still count. In fact it is believed that **deleted questions count more**.

Assuming you deleted the questions and they're salvagable (i.e. not wildly off topic) then edit them into shape and undelete them. If they were deleted by the community edit them into shape then flag to ask a moderator to undelete.

Other positive contributions do count, but no where near as much as improving you're existing content

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188224/220538

Comment: So, what can i do ?

Comment: @Refaat - Undelete your deleted questions, if you have links to them and improve them. Those that are not deleted might also be improved.

Comment: @Refaat Depends (a) are the deleted questions salvageable and (b) were they deleted by you?

Comment: yes all the deleted questions are deleted by me

Comment: @Refaat Not all of them, the Community user deleted one that was old; I've undeleted it to give you a chance to improve it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940370/how-to-assign-input-value-in-html